# jQuery game character movement system

Tags: jquery

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var mUp=false;
        var mLeft=false;
        var mRight=false;

        function movement(){
            $(function(){
                if(mUp){
                    $('.user').animate({
                        bottom: '+=120'
                    },{
                        duration: 50,
                        easing: 'linear',
                        complete: function() {
                            $('.user').animate({
                                bottom: '-=120'
                            },{
                                duration: 150,
                                easing: 'linear',
                                complete: function() {
                                    mUp=false;
                                    if(!mRight&&!mLeft){
                                        $('.user').stop();
                                    }
                                }
                            }).dequeue();
                        }
                    }).dequeue();
                }

                if(mRight){
                    $('.user').animate({
                        left: '+=1000'
                    },{
                        duration: 1000,
                        easing: 'linear',
                    }).dequeue();
                }

                if(mLeft){
                    $('.user').animate({
                        left: '-=1000'
                    },{
                        duration: 1000,
                        easing: 'linear',
                    }).dequeue();
                }
            });
        }



        $(document).keydown(function(e){
            var curKey=e.keyCode;
            if(curKey==39){
                console.log('right+');
                if(!mRight){
                    mRight=true;
                    movement();
                }
            }
            if(curKey==37){
                if(!mLeft){
                    mLeft=true;
                    movement();
                }
            }
            if(curKey==38){
                console.log('up+');
                if(!mUp){
                    mUp=true;
                    movement();
                }
            }
        });

        $(document).keyup(function(e){
            var curKey=e.keyCode;
            if(curKey==39){
                console.log('right-');
                if(!mUp){
                    $('.user').stop();
                }
                mRight=false;
            }
            if(curKey==37){
                console.log('left-');
                if(!mUp){
                    $('.user').stop();
                }
                mLeft=false;
            }
            if(curKey==38){
                console.log('up-');
            }
        });
    });
```

I'm working on a simple movement system for a jQuery based game. I can move the character left or right and jump. My problem begins when trying to move the character left or right while the jump animation is still in progress. If I jump while already moving left or right everything works fine but when I first jump then, while the jump animation is still in effect, try to move left or right it kinda goes crazy.

JSFIDDLE: [CLICK](http://jsfiddle.net/2L86bdw0/)

Comment: I know you don't want this behavior, but I liked it (is like climbing), I would say http://geekwhisperin.files.wordpress.com/2009/09/bug-vs-feature.jpg

Comment: I thought of what you said before posting it but.. The behavior has a mind of it's own. By the looks of it, I'm stuck with it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the animation "up" is executed more than once at the same time.

1. Press up key -> `mUp` becomes `true`, `movement` is called and "up" animation starts.
2. Press left key -> `mLeft` becomes `true`, `movement` is called and because `mUp` is still true "up" animation starts again.

You should check that when you call the movement function animation does not start up if it is already in progress.

```
function movement(){
    $(function(){
        if(mUp && !mUpInProgress){
           //...
        }
     });
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2L86bdw0/1/)